# what should I include in crash report VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crash-reports

Hi I was wondering what information should I include in Unhanded exception reporter (Crash reporter), what information helps me to reproduce the same exception?

Comment: It all depends where the crash is happening (business object, database, web service, ...). Is the data sensitive/protected, ...

Comment: I would appreciate more in depth explanation :) by the way its a winforms application. And no, it does not deal with sensitive data (I guess)

Comment: Are you gathering information for yourself to find bugs or are you sending information to the end user?

Comment: Its for me to find the bug, the program then send the report to me

Comment: All of the information you have, e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  Reproducing it on your own machine only ever works if you are really lucky, don't count on it.

Comment: Send ex.message and ex.tostring. That should get you going.

Comment: Include (if you can) the parameters the method/function received when crashes... that's usually a lot of help